# Select Element whose ID is attribute in another Element

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I select an element whose ID is given in an attribute of another element?

```
<div id="_News" class="link active" data-wife="News">News</div>
```

I want to grab the element with the ID given in `data-wife`. I've tried something like

```
$("'#" + $(this).attr("data-wife") + "'").show();
```

but it looks totally wrong to me (and does not work, of course..).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're doubling up your quotes. You would end up with a selector that was interpreted like this:

```
$("'#News'")
```

Try this instead:

```
$("#" + $(this).attr("data-wife")).show();
```

As a side note, it's simpler and preferable to use `data()` to access `data-` attributes:

```
$("#" + $(this).data("wife")).show();
```

Comment: Wow, that was quick - and correct! Thank you very much. Will accept as soon as possible...

Answer (score 4):

To get the value of "data-" attributes, you can use `.data()`:

```
$('#' + $(this).data('wife')).show();
```

Note that you leave off the "data-" prefix. In your code you introduced an extra layer of quotes, which is incorrect. The library just wants a string, not a string with a quoted string in it.

Answer (score 1):

[*demo*](http://jsbin.com/uzosan/1/edit)

```
$('#_News').click(function(){ 
  $('#'+this.dataset.wife).show();  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Syntax Change

```
$("#" + $(this).attr("data-wife")).show();
```